# Google Contacts feed is breaking gdata-contacts-3.0-1.47.1

Tags: google-api, google-contacts-api, google-people-api

This is for Google API folks.

Not sure when exactly the feed has changed but very recently (today or a couple of days ago). the GDATA library can't process Google Contacts feed anymore, failing with this:

com.yoxel.sync.core.exceptions.SyncException: com.google.gdata.util.ParseException: [Line 30, Column 86, element gContact:website] Invalid value for attribute : 'rel'

value=http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#profile

GDATA library seems to be expecting capital PROFILE but the feed started to send lowercase!

```
for (Enum enumValue : (Enum[])enumClass.getEnumConstants()) {
   if (enumToAttributeValue.getAttributeValue(enumValue).equals(value){
    return enumValue;
 }
}
```

Is there more recent gdata library available?

Thank you.

10/9/20 Update:

For those migrating to the new People API check out our new unified API platform Aurinko.io

Answer (score 2):

Seems like Google contacts feed API is currently broken when creating/updating contacts if a contact has relations/events/websites.

Ticket is already filed at https://issuetracker.google.com/u/0/issues/70209603

Answer (score 1):

It appears that Google has now corrected the problem.